# blob object in an iframe src

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, iframe, httpresponse

I'm trying to to do something that seems to be quite simple: I'm trying to display a window.URL.createObjectURL (of *.pdf file - Blob) in an iframe. I'm trying to do this by binding the iframe src attribute to the output of the window.URL.createObjectURL function.
See my code:
Component Html:

```
<iframe [src]="safeResourceUrl" class="iframe"></iframe>
```

binding the attribute in the component:

```
safeResourceUrl : SafeResourceUrl;
this.safeResourceUrl = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
```

The url seems something like this (example):

"blob:http://localhost:4200/84999abe-5a02-48e0-bf61-f693eb5e0f6b"

This is its content (not a mistake these are HTML tags saved as PDF, but any other content should be also fine):

```
<html>
  <body>
     <label style="color:red;"> test file (HTML) </label>
  </body>
</html>
```

The file path is produced by a Blob that produced from a webApi get request.
the request is configured with :

```
responseType: 'blob'
```

and the blob type is

```
 type: 'application/octet-stream'
```

What am I missing here ?
The file is being downloaded with the correct content, but the iframe content (in the developer tools contains empty HTML tags):

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Please support

Comment: try without `blob` part please "http://localhost:4200/84999abe-5a02-48e0-bf61-f693eb5e0f6b"

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out after few tests:
I set the blob type to be 'application/pdf' instead of the 'application/octet-stream' used for download.

```
const blob = new Blob([res.body], { type: obj.action == FileAction.save ?  'application/octet-stream' : 'application/pdf' }); // preview in a PDF format
```